# MySQL dynamic SELECT column value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My MySQL table has these columns: `Status : int(11)` and `Closed : int(1)`. The thing is that when I retrieve rows with `SELECT`, I want `Closed` to be treated as a `Status` value.

So, whenever `Closed = 1`, I want `Status` to be equal to `-1`. It's important to say that I need `Status` to be stored independently of the `Closed` column. Is that possible to do with the `SELECT` query or do I have to make like a PHP workaround for it ?

Comment: why can't you update the value of Status when Closed getting updated ?

Comment: Because, when the `Closed` value is updated back to `0`, I need the previous `Status` value. That's why `Status` cannot be changed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `CASE` statement

```
SELECT Closed,
CASE
    WHEN Closed = 1 THEN 
    -1
    ELSE Status
END AS Status
FROM <YOUR_TABLE>;
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.